# How reduction is used to prove hardness through contradiction?

Tags: complexity-theory, reduction, np, np-complete, computation

I'm not a student taking a computational complexity course, just interested in the subject. I came across this section:

> Suppose we have a problem that we've proven is hard to solve,
>   and we have a similar new problem. We might suspect that it is also
>   hard to solve. We argue by contradiction: suppose the new problem is
>   easy to solve. Then, if we can show that every instance of the old
>   problem can be solved easily by transforming it into instances of the
>   new problem and solving those, we have a contradiction. This
>   establishes that the new problem is also hard.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity))

I can't seem to wrap my head around what this means. Can you explain this process in layman's terms (as much as possible) how a proof by contradiction as such would work?

Is the contradiction that we know the old problem is hard but we're able to reduce it to a new problem and solving that means old is at least as easy as new? This whole idea is confusing to me. Can someone explain it to me, who doesn't have a solid background in computational complexity theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that we know for a fact that task A is a hard task. Now say we are given task B and asked to determine whether it's hard or not. Pretend that we figure out a way to efficiently break down task A into a few parts and each part turns out to be task B. That is, task A can be easily performed by doing a small number of task Bs. Now, can task B be easy? If it were, then I'd be able to do task A easily as well. That would be a contradiction though, since i know task A to be hard. Therefore task B must be hard as well.

It's important to note that all cases of task A must reduce to B in order for this to hold. If just some cases do then B could be easy but still not provide an easy solution to A in general, therfore there isn't necessarily a contradiction. Also, if it takes a lot to reduce A to B (ie the reduction itself is hard) then there isn't necessarily a contradiction if B is easy.

Comment: Beautifully said. Thank you.

Comment: Follow up question: what if there's the chance that task B is actually easy, and we find out later that it is. Does this mean that task A is now as easy as task B, and this means the entire subset of NP collapses on itself (like NP-completeness) to form one large P class in essence?

Comment: If B turns out to be easy then A is too, as well as every other previously thought to be hard task. This would amount to showing that P=NP.